# font becomes question mark icon on Safari

Tags: css, webfonts

I'm using Safari for Mac on OSX El Capitan (my Mac is early 2009 so doesn't allow any ore updating).

When I visite www.mediamarkt.nl I often see question mark icons where the fonts should be. Like this:

[image: font issue]

I went inside the console and figured out it had something to do with the Geomanist font. Cause when I switch if of on various elements that show those question marks, the texts is readable again. The same when I change Geonamist to for example Arial.

[image: geomanist]

[image: font fixed]

On Chrome it works normally and also on Safari on OSX Sierra (which I can't install cause my Mac is old). I suspect it has something to do with the way the Geomanist font is begin coded into the website. Can someone figure out what is done wrong in this font css coding? Something that isn't quite compatible with older Safari versions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume it has to do with the format of the font file Mediamarkt is serving. Their custom fonts are served in woff2 format, which all modern (evergreen) browsers support. However your older version of Safari might not, as you can see in this support table on caniuse.com, https://caniuse.com/#search=woff2.
Hope this helps.